# Geolocator_android Uses Deprecated Package Manager

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, mobile-application

I have been trying to build a flutter application and I am having the error below

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
/home/chilusoft/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/geolocator_android-3.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/GeolocatorLocationService.java:134: warning: [deprecation] stopForeground(boolean) in Service has been deprecated
      stopForeground(true);
      ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
/home/chilusoft/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/geolocator_android-3.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/permission/PermissionUtils.java:27: warning: [deprecation] getPackageInfo(String,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated
              .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
              ^
1 error
2 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried upgrading the android SDK to 33 and also the permission handler set to 'any'